# Finding the values of certain rows in R data frame

Tags: r

Suppose I have a data frame like this:

```
Obs<-c('C','I','M','M','I','M','C')
df<- data.frame(Obs)
```

The pattern of Cs,Is and Ms is not known beforehand. I would like to:

1. Find the index location of every 'I' that occurs
2. Extract the value that occurs in the row before the occurrence of I
3. Also extract the value that occurs in the row after the occurrence of I

So based on the df example here. I would find rows 2 and 5. As this relates to row 2 then go to row 1 to extract 'C' and then row 3 to extract 'M'. As this relates to row 5 I would go to row 4 to extract 'M' and row 6 to extract 'M'.

I would like to end up with two sets a before and after set for each occurrence of I.

Before = {C, M}
After = {M,M}

My data relates to outcomes before and after 'treatment' I. If there is any other way to collate the before and after please let me know. I started out using match function but need some help.

Comment: What if there were two `I` side by side?

Comment: Then you get `> before
[1] "C" "I" "M"
> after
[1] "I" "M" "M"`

Comment: @TarJae what if `I` is at the beginning or at the end?

Comment: Then it is NULL. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With which we find the index location.
We look before and after (and remove NAs)

```
ind <- which(df$Obs == "I")
before <- df$Obs[ind - 1]
after <- df$Obs[ind + 1]
before <- before[!is.na(before)]
after <- after[!is.na(after)]

before
after
```

```
 before
[1] "C" "M"
> after
[1] "M" "M"
```

Answer (score 3):

`which()` works well.

```r
Obs <- c('C','I','M','M','I','M','C')
w <- which(Obs == 'I')
before <- Obs[w-1]
after <- Obs[w+1]
```

I haven't worried about what happens if there's an 'I' in the first or last spot.